# Jmeter Results analysis

Tags: performance, jmeter

Kindly i need a help in explaining some performance test results:

1. **Load test total **800** user** : we used **8** slaves each one run **100** users with ramp up time **100** sec, we expected **5195** samples (by multiplying number of total users by number of actions (requests)), but we got in the results **4252** sample and when we checked the csv file we found that only **649** user success to start executing the first action (Hit Url) while we were expecting **800** user to start executing the first action (Hit Url).
2. **Stress test total **2500** user** : we used **10** slaves each one run **250** users with ramp up time **250** sec, we expected **15095** samples (by multiplying number of total users by number of actions (requests)), but we got in the results **3185** sample (which is less than the samples we got in the load test) and when we checked the csv file we found that only **515** user success to start executing the first action (Hit Url) while we were expecting **2500** user to start executing the first action (Hit Url).

would you please help me in explaining this ? we not all users can start execute the first request ? is it an indicator for a performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot state anything without seeing your

1. [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) from master and slave machines
3. error messages from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) if any

Given percentage of errors (or not executed requests) gets higher as the number of threads increases it might indicate a performance issue so in addition to the above points I would also recommend:

4. Checking system under test logs for any suspicious entries
5. Ensuring that the server has enough headroom in terms or CPU, RAM, network and disk IO, if you don't have monitoring in place you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
6. Re-running your test having [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled on the server side, this way you will have comprehensive information on the slowest functions, largest objects, deadlocks, etc.